# Onclik na linha do dbgrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema , e tenho um `dbgrid` onde listo resultados de uma `query`, como seria possível quando eu clicar em um certo registro (por exemplo no nome de uma pessoa do campo NOME) , eu fazer abrir outro `form`?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No formulário do `DBGrid`, crie uma `procedure`:

```
procedure DBGridClick(Sender: TObject);
```

Implemente a procedure, fazendo o que desejar. Chame o outro form, etc:

```
procedure TForm1.DBGridClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  frmDetalhes : TfrmDetalhes;
begin
  frmDetalhes := TfrmDetalhes.Create(Application);
  frmDetalhes.pID := dsCliente.DataSet.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;
  frmDetalhes.Show;
end;
```

Para atribuir o evento ao `DBGrid`, no método `create` do `Form`, faça:

```
DBGrid1.ControlStyle := DBGrid1.ControlStyle + [csClickEvents];
TForm(DBGrid1).OnClick := DBGridClick;
```

Aqui habilitamos o `click` e setamos a `procedure` no evento.

Comment: ali ao invés de Executar o comando `Show` execute o `ShowModal`, pois, imagine que o cara clique novamente no grid, teríamos uma violação de memória... +1 Pela Resposta correta!

Comment: @JúniorMoreira correta a observação! +1